# (python 3) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, backup

Am starting to learn python 3. Am reading from "A byte of Python" ebook.
I got the above error when trying to run the following program:

```
# Filename: backup_ver1.py
import os
import time

source = ['C:\\python']

target_dir = 'F:\\Backup' 
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Successful backup to', target)
else:
    print('Backup FAILED')
```

The program prints: Backup FAILED but when trying to run:

```
zip -qr F:\Backup\20140618201605.zip C:\python
```

I get the:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

All routes and folders DO exist, however the idle makes the "F" red!!

This is a screenshot of the error:

[image: A screenshot of the error]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of the error

Comment: Are you **sure** you are running the exact same code in the same environment in both cases? As @MattDMo points out, you should post the full error message. I would add that you should also post the full command line (e.g. `python zip.py blah blah`) used to invoke the program in both cases.

Comment: Running this code using paths that exits in my computer give no errors at all.

Comment: Pfffff why do i get this error then? :/

Comment: Did you tried to run just `zip -qr F:\Backup\20140618201605.zip C:\python` without use python?

Comment: @RubenBermudez I don't get it... I run this command in python environment (Python Shell).

Comment: `zip()` is a python built-in function, but that's not how it works. The example you're using is calling the `zip` unix utility.

Comment: @midkin - can you mark the question as answered please?

Comment: I 've marked your answer as correct (the green check image).
Isn't that what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when trying to run:
>
> ```
> zip -qr F:\Backup\20140618201605.zip C:\python
> ```
>
> I get the:
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

This is because that's a shell command, not Python. You'll never be able to enter that in the Python shell. You should try it in a [Command Prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt) window.

Once you have this working manually, you can discover what errors the Python version is probably running into - it sounds like the zip command either doesn't exist (on your [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)) in which case you should [add an entry to your path](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) for that `zip` program, or it's invalid syntax that's producing an error return code.

Comment: So to make the zip command run I should download the zip command from here? http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zip/3.0/zip-3.0-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=sunet
It's like i tried to use a module that doesn't exist in my pc???

Comment: Well, if you have no program called "zip", then a script that runs any "zip -qr ..." command will always fail, so yes you'd probably need something like this (you'll need to change the exact command used, e.g. to something like "7za" for 7zip). The key is to get the command working manually first.

Comment: I do have 7-zip but this is not what i mean, right?

Comment: My book says that the zip command exists in all Linux/Unix! However, Windows users, should download and install it from: "http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zip/3.0/zip-3.0-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=sunet".
When I download it, and saw it's called: "zip-3.0-setup.exe", I thought its something alternative to the "7-zip" that I already use and didn't install it...
Should I install it to make my module run???

Comment: Yes you should, as that will support the syntax (and executable name) that your script is using.

Comment: pffff downloaded and installed the above .exe file...
Tried to run the code again from IDLE (Run -> Run module) gives me again: Backup Failed"
Tried to run from command prompt gives me this: http://postimg.org/image/4qpbs8j8r/

Any idea?

Comment: You need to run `zip -qr F:\Backup\20140618201605.zip C:\python` in the shell, and get that working. This will probably involve editing your path to include your newly installed `zip` command (see the path link in my answer).

Comment: The right path to add is this: C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin
Where should I add this path in my module? How and where?

Comment: The book says to add "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin" as an environment variable but I don't know what it means...

Comment: Yay! Man, I love u! :D
http://postimg.org/image/x5jiewfwd/
Its a pity I can't vote your post :)))

Answer (score 2):

Your error screenshot shows that you're trying to execute the line

```
 zip -qr F:\Backup\20140618201605.zip C:\python
```

directly in the Python shell. That's not python code. I suspect that you'd get different results if you executed

```
os.system("zip -qr F:\Backup\20140618201605.zip C:\python")
```

in the shell.